# Wordpress - Custom posts fails to export - too many entries?

Tags: php, csv, wordpress, custom-post-type

I think this is a StackOverflow question and not a ServerFault question... but if I'm wrong then I apologize!

I am trying to export a custom post type which has around 500,000 entries. When I export another custom post type that has just a few entries, it exports successfully.

But the second I export the post type with 500,000 entries (by going to Tools->Export), I receive the following error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE


Firefox can't find the file at
http://website.com/wp-admin/export.php?download=true&cat=0&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_status=0&page_author=0&page_start_date=0&page_end_date=0&page_status=0&content=card&submit=Download+Export+File.
```

This is resulting from a 500 error from WordPress:

```
[12/Jun/2015:10:51:47 -0400] "GET /wp-admin/export.php?download=true&cat=0&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_status=0&page_author=0&page_start_date=0&page_end_date=0&page_status=0&content=card&submit=Download+Export+File HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
```

I've tried increasing the upload_max_filesize but unfortunately this has no effect. I'm also not able to find any useful information in the normal logs. I temporarily enabled debug logging within WordPress and the following errors were logged when I tried to export:

```
[12-Jun-2015 14:56:40 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined index: rewrite_withfront in /home/account/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/custom-post-type-ui.php on line 265

[12-Jun-2015 14:56:40 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined index: rewrite_hierarchical in /home/account/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/custom-post-type-ui.php on line 266

[12-Jun-2015 14:56:40 UTC] PHP Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since versiaccounton 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/account/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3508

[12-Jun-2015 14:56:40 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined index: page in /home/account/public_html/wp-content/plugins/order-categories/category-order.php on line 20
```

How would I export all the 500,000 posts within that Custom Post Type?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-exporter/

Comment: @vel I actually tried that plugin but it only exports normal post types, not custom post types.